It would be just as well if you paid me now

It would be just as well if you paid me now.

VS.

It would be just as well if you pay me now.

What's the difference between the two sentences in terms of either 'meaning' or 'grammar'?
And if you are native speakers of English, which one would be more favorable one?
The only apparent difference is 'paid' vs. 'pay' and 'paid' is in the past tense to form 'subjunctive past' and goes along with 'would'.

Your sense is correct. Compare It would be better if she were here. Today many native speakers might say It would be better if she was here, which I myself—an American in my 60s—wouldn’t say. But I don’t think any native English speaker would say *It would be better if she is here to describe a counterfactual. They might say it to describe a hypothetical situation in the future, as in We have an exam tomorrow, so it would be better if she is here (so she can take it). But tour examples can’t be hypothetical future because of the now.
